# Do indexes take effect inmediately after creation? Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to know how long it takes, for an index to take effect after getting created.

Is it instantly?
Do I have to insert, update, delete?
Depends on amount of data? (where do I check?)

Comment: What do you mean by "take effect"? When you create an index (with `create index`), the index is "created" immediately - the required data is retrieved from the table (and/or calculated as needed for calculated indexes) and stored on disk. If something is wrong (for example, you create a unique index but the data has duplicates), you will get an error right away. Even if the underlying table is empty, the index is created immediately (and is also empty).

Comment: And during the insert and update process indexes will be updated automatically. So, many indexes are decreasing insert and update performance.  Sometimes some Databases are needed to recreate all indexes at one time during the year to increase performance. But this is very rarely needed usually.

Comment: Check your query plan - is it using the index or not? Depends on the query against this table - using index may or may not be the best query plan. It will also depend on collected statistics among other factors.

Comment: @TheImpaler - your first reference is to Oracle Text Application (and the text indexing in that context); what does that have to do with the OP's question? And what do you mean by "delay (an index) being populated when needed"? How do you do that? Answer: you don't. What you do delay is **creation** of the index; you can't create the index but delay it being populated.

Answer (score -1):

creating index is a DDL command in oracle and will execute immediately and affects will be used in the future query processing.

be success!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The actual creation of the index may be immediate, but populating it with the necessary data may or may not, depending on the size of the table and the columns indexed.  I can easily see a scenario with a large table where it would take a few minutes for the index to get populated.  And after that, its actual use will depend on the query and what the optimizer decides.